# IIS Permissions to VirtualPrinter

Tags: c#, .net, iis, permissions, virtual-printer

I have the following case,

I'm running an IIS-hosted application that checks a VirtaulPrinter queue at set interval and empty it on certain conditions by using -

```
_printer.InvokeMethod("CancelAllJobs", null);
```

Giving the VirtualPrinter full permission to Everyone works fine, but giving write and modify permission just to IUSR results in no access permission exception.

I would prefer to avoid giving the Virtual Printer full access to everyone and give permission  only to the my IIS-hosted application.

Do I need to give permissions to another group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to check the permissions for the identity of the Application Pool that your website is using.